# divisibility of $n^{2}+n+1$ by $6k-1$ when $n,k$ are integers.

Tags: number-theory

I wanted to prove that for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the integer $n^{2}+n+1$ does not have
any divisors of the form $6k-1$.
  So far, I proved $n^{2}+n+1\neq-1 \pmod 6$ and an integer which is $-1\pmod6$ should have a prime factor which is also $-1 \pmod6$.
 And I was trying to assume $n^{2}+n+1\equiv0\mathrm\,{(mod \;6k-1)}\Rightarrow n^{2}\equiv-n-1(mod\;6k-1)\,$, where $6k-1$ is prime here, and use the quadratic reciprocity law to find some contradiction (since the question was an exercise in the chapter of quadratic reciprocity from some lecture note) but after a while, I couldn't find anything useful yet.
 Any hint please? I only know some elementary number theory.

Comment: Hint: If a prime $p$ divides $n^2+n+1$, it also divides $(n-1)(n^2+n+1) = n^3-1$.

Comment: Wow... it was so easy after all this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting the hint to an answer:

If a prime $p$ divides $n^2+n+1$, then it also divides $(n-1)(n^2+n+1) = n^3-1$.

Now, if a prime $p$ divides $n^3-1$, then either $p$ divides $n-1$, or the multiplicative order of $n$ modulo $p$ is $3$, which implies $3 \mid (p-1)$, and thus $p = 6k+1$ for some $k > 0$. If $p$ divides $n-1$ and $n^2+n+1$, it also divides their greatest common divisor, which is a divisor of $(n^2+n+1) - (n-1)(n+2) = 3$. So a prime dividing $n^2+n+1$ can only be $3$ or of the form $6k+1$.